# google oauth callback appending parameters multiple times

Tags: callback, google-oauth, query-string

We have successfully using Google OAuth for years now, but it suddenly stopped working a few days ago.  In looking into this, it appears that the after the user clicks "Allow" to grant access to the requested scope, Google is redirecting to our callback page (as it always has) but now the code and scope parameters are being appended to the URL multiple times (example below).  Given querystring length limits on our web server, this is now throwing a 404.15 error.

Since we have made no recent code changes and have not made any updates in the Google API Console, I don't believe we have done anything to cause the parameters to be appended multiple times to the callback URL.  Is this an issue with Google?  Or am I missing something that may have caused this issue?

Example callback URL:

http://example.com/oauth/oauthcallback?code=4/XADj4OhPIwWZRA5TsZMgOkMIfmuBVdQidarK_MhSmkpxWubmprbySMBnY4huJaYATwzf8B798OcHLfD-LdBBtfQ&scope=https://googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly&code=4/XADj4OhPIwWZRA5TsZMgOkMIfmuBVdQidarK_MhSmkpxWubmprbySMBnY4huJaYATwzf8B798OcHLfD-LdBBtfQ&scope=https://googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly&code=4/XADj4OhPIwWZRA5TsZMgOkMIfmuBVdQidarK_MhSmkpxWubmprbySMBnY4huJaYATwzf8B798OcHLfD-LdBBtfQ&scope=https://googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly&code=4/XADj4OhPIwWZRA5TsZMgOkMIfmuBVdQidarK_MhSmkpxWubmprbySMBnY4huJaYATwzf8B798OcHLfD-LdBBtfQ&scope=https://googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly&code=4/XADj4OhPIwWZRA5TsZMgOkMIfmuBVdQidarK_MhSmkpxWubmprbySMBnY4huJaYATwzf8B798OcHLfD-LdBBtfQ&scope=https://googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly&code=4/XADj4OhPIwWZRA5TsZMgOkMIfmuBVdQidarK_MhSmkpxWubmprbySMBnY4huJaYATwzf8B798OcHLfD-LdBBtfQ&scope=https://googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly&code=4/XADj4OhPIwWZRA5TsZMgOkMIfmuBVdQidarK_MhSmkpxWubmprbySMBnY4huJaYATwzf8B798OcHLfD-LdBBtfQ&scope=https://googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly&code=4/XADj4OhPIwWZRA5TsZMgOkMIfmuBVdQidarK_MhSmkpxWubmprbySMBnY4huJaYATwzf8B798OcHLfD-LdBBtfQ&scope=https://googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly&code=4/XADj4OhPIwWZRA5TsZMgOkMIfmuBVdQidarK_MhSmkpxWubmprbySMBnY4huJaYATwzf8B798OcHLfD-LdBBtfQ&scope=https://googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly&code=4/XADj4OhPIwWZRA5TsZMgOkMIfmuBVdQidarK_MhSmkpxWubmprbySMBnY4huJaYATwzf8B798OcHLfD-LdBBtfQ&scope=https://googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly&code=4/XADj4OhPIwWZRA5TsZMgOkMIfmuBVdQidarK_MhSmkpxWubmprbySMBnY4huJaYATwzf8B798OcHLfD-LdBBtfQ&scope=https://googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly&code=4/XADj4OhPIwWZRA5TsZMgOkMIfmuBVdQidarK_MhSmkpxWubmprbySMBnY4huJaYATwzf8B798OcHLfD-LdBBtfQ&scope=https://googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly&code=4/XADj4OhPIwWZRA5TsZMgOkMIfmuBVdQidarK_MhSmkpxWubmprbySMBnY4huJaYATwzf8B798OcHLfD-LdBBtfQ&scope=https://googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly&code=4/XADj4OhPIwWZRA5TsZMgOkMIfmuBVdQidarK_MhSmkpxWubmprbySMBnY4huJaYATwzf8B798OcHLfD-LdBBtfQ&scope=https://googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly&code=4/XADj4OhPIwWZRA5TsZMgOkMIfmuBVdQidarK_MhSmkpxWubmprbySMBnY4huJaYATwzf8B798OcHLfD-LdBBtfQ&scope=https://googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly&code=4/XADj4OhPIwWZRA5TsZMgOkMIfmuBVdQidarK_MhSmkpxWubmprbySMBnY4huJaYATwzf8B798OcHLfD-LdBBtfQ&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this.  In case this helps someone else, sometime between 9/12/2018 and 9/14/2018, Google started returning an additional parameter ("scope") in their OAuth callback (in addition to the only other parameter - "code" - that was previously being returned in the callback).  The scope value included "https://www.googleapis.com" which was causing an issue with an existing URL rewrite rule on our end to strip "www" from our URL. The very generic syntax in our rewrite rule that simply looked for "www." was causing a redirect loop until a 404.15 was thrown.  By making the rewrite rule specific to our URL, the scope parameter is ignored by the rewrite rule and the redirect loop is avoided.

Comment: This was happening to me too. Though now I fixed that, it looks like Google is redirecting back to my app with a `#` appended to the very end of the URL and I think that's breaking the auth flow now. Not sure why yet why that's appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Posting because this may help others. @fzebra's answer applied in my case but ALSO my auth library forwards all query parameters that the OAuth provider sends to my `redirect_uri` onto the requests it makes to retrieve the `access_token`. Because of this and because I think Google has a parsing bug, the new `scope` parameter blows up the request. Google responds with a `400 Bad Request` and inspecting the JSON response, you get a `redirect_uri_mismatch`. My guess is they see *their own* `scope` URL parameter as the redirect URI and invalidate the request.

To solve this, I needed to chop the `scope` query parameter off the outgoing request to Google, so I did it via a URL rewrite rule.

```
    <!-- See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52372359/google-oauth-callback-appending-parameters-multiple-times -->
    <rule name="Google Login - Remove scope parameter" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="google/redirect/url(.*)?$" />
        <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)(&amp;?scope=.+&amp;?)(.*)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="google/redirect/url?{C:1}{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

This cuts the `scope` parameter and value out from the incoming query string and joins the two parts back together without it. Note the `&amp;` is because this is XML, in plain regex the expression is just `(.*)(&?scope=.+&?)(.*)`. It will leave a trailing `&` in some cases.

You should replace `google/redirect/url` with the path to your auth URL (that Google redirects to).

You could do this in application layer code but URL rewrite does not add an extra server request

This fixed it finally. Jeez!