# Strip URLs from querystring in web.config

Tags: angular, azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I am using Google to authenticate users through OAuth2. The site is built in Angular 5 and hosted in an Azure App Service (IIS). When google authenticates the user, it sends back an URL which contains some URIs:

`https://domain.azurewebsites.net/membership/oauth2?code=<authentication code>&scope=openid%20email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`.

As you can see, after the `&scope`, there are 2 URIs. azure websites returns an error indicating that

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

If I strip the query string from `&scope` onwards, it works fine.

I have tried to strip that part in web.config with a rewrite rule:

```
    <rule name="Remove paging parameters" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)\/membership\/oauth2(.*)$" />
        <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^(.*)(scope=.+)(.*)$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

However, nothing happens. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Side Note: everything works fine in localhost, as it is nodejs that serves the Angular site. The problem arouses in the Azure App Service, as it is served by IIS.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same issue in the future, I solved this following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52435984/2608521) answer by [@kamranicus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109458/kamranicus). The correct rewrite url showed in that post is as follows:

```
<rule name="Google Login - Remove scope parameter" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="google/redirect/url(.*)?$" />
   <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
       <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)(&amp;?scope=.+&amp;?)(.*)" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="google/redirect/url?{C:1}{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```